# Display different profile (in Drupal) based on CiviGroup (or tag)

Tags: contacts, profile, drupal-views, smartgroups

Thanks in advance
Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.13

I am looking for a way to display different profiles, in Drupal, based on different groups that the contact belongs to in Civi (or based on different tags if that works).

Specifically, I have people to be appointed as members (they already have accounts both in Drupa and Civi), to be given a yes/no field (I accept the appointment) plus some extra bio stuff they need to fill in. I do not want users that are not members to see that under their profile, in Drupal.

I hoped to have to Civi profiles, one for "appointment to be" and one for everyone else and trigger which one is displayed, based on Civigroups (or tags).

Any ideas?

Best A.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly when working with complex form requirements in Drupal, folk are opting to use webform_civicrm as the flexibility it provides opens up many new options.

For example in your case you could use Webform Conditionals to determine which fields show based on the choice of Membership Type (or type an existing user has if they are logged in or using a checksum). HTH